# VBA App Crashes w/o Error Message - Works when stepping through program

Tags: vba, excel, crash, race-condition

I have an excel application that often, but not always crashes, when run normally. In case you set a breakpoint and step through the program, it never fails. Likewise if you set breakpoints at strategic places, and then continues executing it generally also works well.

The issue appears to be related to opening a file, copying a large amount of data, and then closing the file. I am however unsure where the program actually crashes. Tips for debugging / methods for finding where the error occurs in the code would be most appreciated.

I have assumed this is due to either a race condition or memory problems, but unsure exactly what would cause either of those errors. Race condition seems more likely though, as pausing or stepping through application shouldn't help with memory issues. If race condition is the cause of the problem, is there a better solution than letting the application sleep/wait at certain points? How do I identify the points where I would need to sleep/wait?

EDIT: When running the application normally it seems to run longer than you would expect, then just closes without any error message. I am running Excel 2013 (32bit) on Win 10.

I considered data being saved to cliboard being the issue, and added

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

after each paste, this did not resolve the issue though.

I am supressing alerts and screen updating, i.e.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

but commenting out these settings, still causes application to crash.

EDIT2: Adding the code where the crash occurs. Errors appears to occur somewhere in ReadInAndCopyFiles.

```
Sub ReadInFiles(wb As Workbook, FolderPath As String, FileName As String)
Dim CurrentWeekDate As Date
Dim TempDate As Date
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim DataFileName As String
Dim OpenDialog As Office.FileDialog
Dim DateString As String
Dim SheetNameArray As Variant


'Initialization
CurrentWeekDate = wb.Worksheets("Config").Range("EndOfWeekDate").Value
ChDir (FolderPath)

If FileName = "Weekly utilization" Then
    SheetNameArray = Array("WeeklyUtilization_CW", "WeeklyUtilization_CW-1", "WeeklyUtilization_CW-2", "WeeklyUtilization_CW-3")
Else
    SheetNameArray = Array("Charged Hours", "ChargedHours_CW-1", "ChargedHours_CW-2", "ChargedHours_CW-3")
End If

'Current Week
TempFilePath = FolderPath + FileName + ".xlsx"
ReadInAndCopyFile TempFilePath, CStr(SheetNameArray(0)), "Find " & FileName

'Current Week -1
TempDate = DateAdd("d", -7, CurrentWeekDate)
DateString = Format(TempDate, "yy-mm-dd")
TempFilePath = FolderPath + "Archives\" + FileName + " " + DateString + ".xlsx"
ReadInAndCopyFile TempFilePath, CStr(SheetNameArray(1)), "Find " & FileName & " -1"

'Current Week -2
TempDate = DateAdd("d", -14, CurrentWeekDate)
DateString = Format(TempDate, "yy-mm-dd")
TempFilePath = FolderPath + "Archives\" + FileName + " " + DateString + ".xlsx"
ReadInAndCopyFile TempFilePath, CStr(SheetNameArray(2)), "Find " & FileName & " -2"

'Current Week -3
TempDate = DateAdd("d", -21, CurrentWeekDate)
DateString = Format(TempDate, "yy-mm-dd")
TempFilePath = FolderPath + "Archives\" + FileName + " " + DateString + ".xlsx"
ReadInAndCopyFile TempFilePath, CStr(SheetNameArray(3)), "Find " & FileName & " -3"

End Sub

Sub ReadInAndCopyFile(TempFilePath As String, TargetSheetName As String, CustomMessage As String)
Dim DataFileName As String
Dim SourceWb, wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow, LastColumn, StartRow, TargetLastRow As Variant
Dim OpenDialog As Office.FileDialog

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

DataFileName = Dir(TempFilePath)
If Not DataFileName <> "" Then
    MsgBox CustomMessage
    Set OpenDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    OpenDialog.Filters.Clear
    OpenDialog.Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx"
    OpenDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    OpenDialog.Show
    TempFilePath = OpenDialog.SelectedItems(1)
End If

Workbooks.Open FileName:=TempFilePath, UpdateLinks:=False
Set SourceWb = ActiveWorkbook

'Determine where to start pasting, and if header should be included or not
If (wb.Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row = 1) Then
    StartRow = 1
Else
    StartRow = wb.Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End If

'Copy First Sheet
LastRow = SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Dont copy any data if blank
If LastRow <> 1 Then
    LastColumn = SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If StartRow = 1 Then
        Range(SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1), SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Copy
    Else
        Range(SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1), SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Copy
    End If

    wb.Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Range("A" + CStr(StartRow)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    TargetLastRow = wb.Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End If



'Copy Second Sheet
LastRow = SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Dont copy any data if blank
If LastRow <> 1 Then
    LastColumn = SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Copy from row 2 to avoid copying headers again
    Range(SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1), SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Copy
    wb.Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Range("A" + CStr(TargetLastRow + 1)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If

SourceWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: you could add  msgbox  commands before and after sections and then note which is the last msgbox you see before it crashes. You can then home in to the offending line. Of course the pause while it shows the message may itself prevent the crash - in which case you can remove error messages until it does crash

Comment: Hard to say anything without seeing a concrete code, and the information on which line it fails. Please update your question with your code or better an [mcve] to reproduce the crash. Also make sure you are on the latest build version of Excel otherwise update first. Including your Excel version and if it is x86/x64 edition would also be a good idea I think.

Comment: You can start with DoEvents. It helped me sometimes with similar issues. Not guaranteed, but worth trying, as it does not pause program unnecessarily.

Comment: You haven't explain HOW it "crashes". Does it simply stop responding? Is the application window visible when your code does this? You say you copy a large amount of data to the clipboard - any chance a message asking whether the data should be kept on the clipboard is waiting for an answer?

Comment: In very generic terms you can create a new worksheet in your workbook, then add lines of code to write to column 1, row "x" and use that as a trace log. Have your code write to this log sheet before every step of the code so when the "crash" occurs, you'll know the last "real" line of code executed before the crash. Of course, if "crash" means "Excel is shutting down with no warning", this won't help, but we need to know that to even begin to help you.

Comment: @FreeMan yes, the application shuts down with no warning. I have been thinking if it is possible to write to an actual file every now and then instead, to get around this issue.

Comment: Just a note but if you declare `Dim SourceWb, wb As Workbook` then only `wb` is declared as `Workbook` but `SourceWb` is of type `Variant`. You need to declare a type for **every** variable: `Dim SourceWb As Workbook, wb As Workbook`. Also `LastRow, LastColumn, StartRow, TargetLastRow` should all be `Long` not `Variant`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this bit

```
Dim OpenDialog As Office.FileDialog

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

DataFileName = Dir(TempFilePath)
If Not DataFileName <> "" Then
    MsgBox CustomMessage
    Set OpenDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    OpenDialog.Filters.Clear
    OpenDialog.Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx"
    OpenDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    OpenDialog.Show
    TempFilePath = OpenDialog.SelectedItems(1)
End If
```

Replace with this

```
Dim s
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
datafilename = Dir(tempfilepath)
If datafilename = "" Then
s = Application.GetOpenFilename("*.xlsx,Excel Files", 1, "Select File", , False)
If Not s = False Then
    tempfilepath = s
End If
End If
```

Comment: The files will generally always exist, and during my tests runs there are guaranteed to be files that match, so I have never had to select files, so even if this section could cause issues, there would have to be other problems as well then.

Comment: you are referencing the office.filedialog every time even if you never use it - I think it's the call out to that that is the problem. At least move the dim inside the if loop

Comment: I tried removing the option of selecting a file if not found and tried to run it, but unfortunately still crashes. So either this does not solve the issue, or there are multiple issues.

Answer (score 0):

I wasa able to resolve the issue by adding Application.Wait in two places in the code for the sub ReadInAndCopyFile.

```
'Firstplace
Workbooks.Open FileName:=TempFilePath, UpdateLinks:=False
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
Set SourceWb = ActiveWorkbook

'Second place
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
SourceWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

The placement is only due to where I assumed the errors were occurring. It is entirely possible that only one Wait would be enough, and that a shorter wait would be ok. I may do further experimenting later, but for now it is enough that it is running.

Happy to hear if anyone has better or faster methods for resolving this, as this methods as a significant amount of time to the total running time.